# Visio object not appearing

Tags: python, visio

I am trying to code a program to generate a template in visio. I'm using python 3.9 for this. My code looks something like this:

```
visio = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Visio.Application')
visio.Visible = True

stencilPath = "*path to stencil*"

document = visio.Documents.Add("")
stencil = visio.Documents.Open(stencilPath)
page = document.Pages.Item(1)
shape = stencil.Masters.Item("*name of shape*")
shape1 = page.Drop(shape, 0, 0)
```

This is working fine.As far as I understand the drop method asks for the shape, the xPos and the yPos (correct me if i'm mistaken).

But I'm facing an issue with placing the shapes at the correct location. If i replace the shape1 variable with:

```
page.Drop(shape, 50, 50)
```

Visio won't place the shape. I do not get an error and the program doesn't crash.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"50, 50" is in *inches* ("internal units"). Not pixels. Inches. Most probably, your shape is somewhere outside of the page (it is allowed to have shapes outside of the page), and you will be able to see it if you zoom out.

Comment: That's really useful to know.